# Как задавать размер ячейкам (3 кастомные ячейки) взависимости от содержимого?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, height, tableview

Имеется таблица, в ней 3 кастомные ячейки. В зависимости от типа данных берётся та или иная ячейка. Но данные разных размеров.

Во всех ячейках данные вставляются в 3 `textView` и одну `imageView`. Надо чтобы ячейка получалась нужного размера,в зависимости от всего этого контента.

В `heightForRowAtIndexPath` высчитываю размеры, и возвращаю размер. Вроде как размер получаю правильный, но ячейка все равно получается стандартной, размер получает из того что указано в сториборде и все ячейки одного размера. пс, в `Google` искал 3 дня бьюсь не получается.

Comment: а `heightForRowAtIndexPath` точно вызывается?

Comment: А ячейки не как Static Cells ли в Interface Builder, случайно, собраны?

Comment: точно вызывается, статик не стоит)